# Cypress send special character in windows credentials login

Tags: cypress

I've to pass the special characters in windows credentials to log in to the site. I've tried with `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` both methods. And still, it does not work. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my cypress test code:

`test.specs.js`

```
describe("test", () => {
    it('visit site', () => {
        var username = encodeURIComponent("test@username.com")
        var password = encodeURIComponent("password@#123!")
        cy.visit("https://"+ username +":" + password + "@testsite.com")
     //cy.visit("https://test@username.com:password@#123!@testsite.com")
    })
})
```

> It's working fine when there is no special character for username and password.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It works with example.com `cy.visit("https://"+ username +":" + password + "@example.com")`, so I'd say the encoding is correct and Cypress is handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this one : `` ` `` ?

```
describe('test', () => {
    it('visit site', () => {
        var username = `test@username.com`;
        var password = `password@#123!`;
        cy.visit(`https://${username}:${password}@testsite.com`)
     //cy.visit(`https://${username}:${password}@testsite.com`)
    })
})
```

Comment: This is not working also. This problem working fine by using `python selenium` using this code: `browser.get('http://test%40username.com:password%40%23123!@testsite.com')`